# Is there any standard protocol to transfer RSA encrypted text over a network?

Tags: go, encryption, tcp, client-server, rsa

I have a client and a server side code. I have to take a message as input from the client, encrypt it and send it to the server. But when I print this encrypted message on the server side, it is not the same as it was on the client side. Here's how I am doing this:

First I am encrypting the message using `rsa.EncryptOAEP()` function. The message is a member of a struct which has other members too. I am encoding this struct with the gob package and sending it to the server.

Here's the snippet of client side code:

```
func SocketClient() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":9000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
    buff, _ := input_reader.ReadBytes('\n')    //this is the message to be encrypted
    label := []byte("")
    hash := sha256.New()
    ciphertext, _ := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
        hash,
        rand.Reader,
        &receiverPublicKey,
        buff,
        label,
    )
    fmt.Printf("%s",ciphertext) //this is to check if the text is same or not
    block.Message = ciphertext //this is the struct to be sent over network
    enc.Encode(block)
}
```

Here's the server side code:

```
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
    dec.Decode(&block)
    fmt.Printf("%s",block.Message) //it is different from the text printed in client side code
}
```

When I am printing the message, it should be the same on both the side. So is there some standard protocol or something to deal with encrypted texts?

Comment: To transmit any data securely by default SSL is used, creating a secure channel, which is transparent for the client and server.  `it should be same on both the side` try to print out encoded messages (not the raw byte arrays), if there are not the same, I'd just guess it has nothing to do with encryption, but rather with a way you send/read the data, which is not visible in the code

Comment: Actually I found the bug. The rsa.EncryptOAEP() returns a []uint8 type variable and I was using []byte and it was not getting typecaste properly.

Comment: @abhisheksingla: there is no typecasting in Go, and `[]uint8` and `[]byte` are identical (`byte` is and internal alias for `uint8`). Also, the `%s` in the `Printf` statements would attempt to convert both to a `string` anyway, so there's no reason they shouldn't print the exact same thing.

Comment: "is there some standard protocol or something to deal with encrypted texts?" yes, many many many of them, from HTTPS to SSH, with varying capabilities and target use cases.